# Rust "use of borrowed...." compilation error

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutable

I have a list of node

```
struct ListNode {
  val: i32,
  next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

impl ListNode {
  fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    ListNode {
      next: None,
      val
    }
  }
}
```

And then I have a traverse function (The code is simplified here just for an example).

```
fn traverse(mut list: Option<Box<ListNode>>) {
    let mut ptr = &mut list;
    let mut counter = 0;

    while counter < 5 {

        match ptr {
            None => {
                break;
            },
            Some(ptr_node) => { 
                if true {
                    ptr = &mut ptr_node.next;
                }
            }
        }

        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

When I compile this code I get this compilation error

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `*ptr` because it was mutably borrowed
   |
   |         match ptr {
   |               ^^^
   |               |
   |               use of borrowed `ptr.0`
   |               borrow later used here
...
   |             Some(ptr_node) => { 
   |                  -------- borrow of `ptr.0` occurs here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `ptr.0` as mutable more than once at a time
   |
   |             Some(ptr_node) => { 
   |                  ^^^^^^^^ `ptr.0` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 2 warnings emitted
```

But if I change my traverse function to this

```
fn traverse(mut list: Option<Box<ListNode>>) {
    let mut ptr = &mut list;
    let mut counter = 0;

    while counter < 5 {

        match ptr {
            None => {
                break;
            },
            Some(ptr_node) => { 
                ptr = &mut ptr_node.next;
            }
        }

        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

Basically, I removed the "if" statement from the code.
This compiles successfully.

Can anyone explain why the "if" statement causing a compilation error?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of my own question: [Why does conditional assignment of a matched mutable reference cause borrow errors?](/q/64639030/2189130) which boils down to a limitation of the current borrow checker.

Comment: Rgarding the bounty, is there a reason the existing answer isn't reputable? or are you just looking for more info?

Comment: Just looking for more info about this. Thanks for you link, will gather more info from that @kmdreko

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a false positive in the current borrow checker ("NLL").

There are a [few known weaknesses of the current borrow checker](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/latest/polonius_the_crab/#rationale-limitations-of-the-nll-borrow-checker). Most of them will get resolved with the new borrow checker, "polonius". Sadly it isn't released yet, so situations like this happen.

A good indication for that is the fact that your code compiles fine with:

```
RUSTFLAGS="-Z polonius" cargo +nightly build
```

The workarounds for the problems are based on the exact situation, more info can be found [here](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab).

I'm not sure how to guide you in your specific situation, though, because the obvious recommendation is to remove the `if true`.